# getting max and min of five input from user

Tags: java, class, methods, max, min

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Compare
{
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;

    public void max(int num)
    {
        if(num > max)
        {
            max = num;
        }
    }
    public void min(int num)
    {
        if(num < min)
        {
            min = num;
        }
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Compare compare = new Compare();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int sets = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < sets ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                int num_main = input.nextInt();
                compare.max(num_main);
                compare.min(num_main);
            }
            System.out.println(compare.max);
            System.out.println(compare.min);
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to calculate max and min of five inputs from the user, i managed to get max value but failed to get the min value instead i am getting 0 as my min value which was initialized from before in class Compare. How can i get the min value in the simplest possible way

Comment: set your min variable in Compare class to Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: and also set you max variable to Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: use `Integer` class which is Nullable and define it as null then test against null also

Comment: Its giving you 0 because you always going to consider 0 as initial value which is less than any positive int. If you want to check just put -1 as input you will get how its flow is going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will give you an Idea**

> I modified your Compare class. I used wrapper classes as instance variable data types.

```
class Compare
{
Integer max;
Integer min;

public void max(int num)
{
    if (max == null) max = num;
    else if(num > max) max = num;
}

public void min(int num)
{
    if (min == null) min = num;
    else if(num < min) min = num;
}
}
```

> Now you will get what output you want.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for you getting 0 as your min value is because when u call `compare.min(num);` your value is getting compared to a predefined local value `min` which is equal to 0.

And when you compare anything positive to 0 you will get 0 as the min value.

A viable solution would be

```
class Compare
{
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;


public void max(int num)
    {
        if(num > max)
        {
            max = num;
        }
    }
    public void min(int num)
    {
        if(num < min)
        {
            min = num;
        }
    }
}
```

this will guarantee that what ever you compare first will be saved as the ***min*** value and hence-forth be used as the new min value for your entire program execution.

Comment: @DedicatedUser replace your int min = 0; with int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Answer (score 0):

You may simplify this with a flag to track first input and then compare the rest with the same.

```
class Demo{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Compare c = new Compare();
        try(java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)){
            int i = 1;
            final int m = 5;
            while(m>=i){
                System.out.printf("Numer %d of %d: ", i, m);
                if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                    c.process(sc.nextInt());
                    i ++;
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Kindly input numbers only!");
                sc.nextLine();/* clear input */
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Max: %d, Min: %d%n", c.getMax(), c.getMin());
    }
}

class Compare{

    private int min;
    private int max;
    private boolean first = true;

    public int getMin(){
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax(){
        return max;
    }

    public void process(int val){
        if(first){
            this.min = this.max = val;
            first = false;
            return;
        }
        if(this.min > val){
            this.min = val;
        }
        if(this.max < val){
            this.max = val;
        }
    }
}
```